# How to populate datagrid with data from different tables?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a table where one column is contract-type and it is represented with an integer, which is the PK in another table which has the contract name and information.

I know how to get all the data. But I don't know how to present it in the same datagrid (at least not best practice). Do I have to make my own class that holds all the properties that I want and then present them? Is it better ways to do it? It doesn't have to be according to the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Are you using EF or you are biding your `DataGrid` with some `DataTable`?

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 options:

1. load the query result into your own class representing the view by hand, assigning values column by column in the loop
2. create the view in the database matching the view of your grid and then loading the data will be much easier.

Comment: Do you have aa article or something for your second alternative? My sql knowledge is limited. thx.

Comment: Example of a view

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-views.htm

CREATE VIEW aRandomView AS
select contract.Id, contract.Description, contractType.Type
from Contract
inner join ContractType  on ContractType.Id = Contract.TypeId


or something to that regard....

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, it is *always* best to provide data in the correct structure. Custom classes *don't* match database tables, as they are usually normalised and we have no need for that in WPF. In your case, you should declare a `Contract` class that has all of the column names from the `Contract` table as properties. Surely, the foreign key `Id` property is in that table too?

The way to 'join' your `Contract` class with whatever table the foreign key was in is to add a property of type `Contract` into the class representing your other table:

```
public Contract Contract [ get; set; }
```

Then in XAML, you can reference it like this for example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding YourOtherObject.Contract.Name}" ... />
```

Comment: Hi, there is no FK. Its a very old and poorley structured database. Can i still apply this?

Comment: A foreign key column is still a foreign key column even if it has no constraint added to the database table, so despite other opinions, yes, you can. It still uses a uniquely identifiable column value from another table to identify items from that table.

Comment: but without a constraint there could be data issues especially if as he/she mentioned it is old and poorly structured

Comment: Regardless of whether there could be data issues in the database, the answer is still, yes. @Chris, please note that this is *not* a question about defining database tables correctly.

Comment: Fair enough, but I am assuming just enforcing a foreign key would save him from getting errors down the line in the join of the two tables and wonder why it isn't working.

Comment: That's an admirable quality, but we can't answer unasked questions here, because there are potentially, so many of them.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using EF 4.0, then you shouldn't bind you `DataGridColumn` with `contract-type` field, instead you should bind it with `Contract.ContractName`

Let's understand with example: Assume that you have following two tables

```
Contract { ContractID, ContractName, ContractInfo }

Client {ClientID, ClientName, ContractType} where ContractType is foreign key from Contract.ContractID
```

Now in EF you will have `Client` class where you will have a property `Contract` with the type `Contract` as follows

```
public Contract Contract {get; set;}
```

This property will point the same `Contract` row which is reference by your `ContractType` field.

So in DataGridColumn you can provide binding like as below:

```
{Binding Contract.ContractName}
```

Now as per above example you can replace `Client` class with the class you are binding with `DataGrid` and the `Contract` class with your contract table name.

Let me know if you have any confusion in this.